# ¿Como puedo mandar a llamar mi imagen para un session, para que el usuario que entre tenga su propio nombre de usuario y foto de perfil?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Mi codigo de session es el siguiente.

```
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contra = $_POST['contra'];
$id_cargo = $_POST['id_cargo'];


session_start();

$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;


$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "condominio");

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario='$usuario' and contra='$contra'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

$filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

if ($filas['id_cargo'] == 1) {
    header("location:xAdmin.php");
} else
if ($filas['id_cargo'] == 2) {
    header("location:index.html");
} else
if ($filas['id_cargo'] == '') {
    header("location: xLogin.php?fallo=true");
}
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Y mi problema es que no se como mandar a llamar mi imagen para que el usuario una vez que inicie se muestre.
Y mi codigo donde subo la foto es este

```
include 'ConexionABaseCondominio.php';
$dataTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$paterno = $_POST['paterno'];
$materno = $_POST['materno'];
$correo = $_POST['correo'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$contra = $_POST['contra'];
$id_cargo = $_POST['id_cargo'];

$dir = "imgw/";

$nombre_archivo = ($_FILES['imagen']['name']);

copy($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'], 'imgw/' . $_FILES['imagen']['name']);


$consulta = $conexion->query("INSERT into usuarios (id,nombre, paterno, materno, correo, telefono, usuario, contra, image, created, id_cargo) 
VALUES (null, '$nombre','$paterno','$materno','$correo','$telefono','$usuario', '$contra','" . $dir . $nombre_archivo . "','$dataTime','$id_cargo')");

echo 'Todo Correcto </br><a href="index.html">Regresar</a></br>';
```

Como lo dije anterioirmente, el usuario ya he logrado que se me pase en una variable haciendo esto
Pero lo que no logro hacer es traer mi foto para imprimirla ):

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que estás usando para traer/mostrar la imagen y qué problema o error tienes al respecto?

Comment: Eso es lo que quiero hacer, no se como traer la imagen

Answer (score 0):

Estás creando la variable de sesión antes de validar el acceso y eso representa un serio problema de seguridad.

Adicionalmente, te recomiendo usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) para evitar ataques y prevenir errores.

```
session_start(); // Esta debe ser siempre la primera instrucción
// Hay que hacer asignación ternaria para evitar errores
$usuario = (isset($_POST['usuario'])) ? $_POST['usuario'] : '';
$contra = (isset($_POST['contra'])) ? $_POST['contra'] : '';
$id_cargo = (isset($_POST['id_cargo'])) ? $_POST['id_cargo'] : '';

// Inicializar variable de sesión
$_SESSION['usuario'] = '';

if(empty($usuario) || empty($contra) || empty($cargo)) {
    // Hay datos que no se llenaron, no se debe procesar
    header("location: xLogin.php?fallo=true");
    // Finalizar ejecución
    exit;
}

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "condominio");
// Usar consulta preparada
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios where usuario=? and contra=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $consulta);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $usuario, $contra);
$resultado = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
if(!$filas || $filas['id_cargo'] == '') {
    // El usuario no existe o id_cargo es incorrecto
    header("location: xLogin.php?fallo=true");
    exit;
}
// El usuario existe, puedes crear variables de sesión
$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
// Variable con la imagen
$_SESSION['image'] = $filas['image'];
// Variable con cargo, seguramente la necesitarás después
$_SESSION['id_cargo'] = $filas['id_cargo'];

// Ahora sí puedes redirigir
if ($filas['id_cargo'] == 1) {
    header("location:xAdmin.php");
} else
if ($filas['id_cargo'] == 2) {
    header("location:index.html");
}
// No es necesario cerrar resultados ni conexión a base de datos
// PHP lo hace automáticamente al terminar el script
```

Comment: Me da error el codigo en 4 lineas ):

Comment: En estas dos el ; al final
$contra =  (isset($_POST['contra'])  ? $_POST['contra'] : '';
$id_cargo =(isset($_POST['id_cargo']) ? $_POST['id_cargo'] : '';

Aqui toda la linea
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($consulta);
Y aqui antes del parentesis
mysqli_stmt_bindparam($stmt, 'ss', $usuario, $contra);

Comment: Y al momento de hacerlo en el login me sale esto "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Examen\validar.php on line 5"

Comment: Ya no deberías tener errores: Faltaban paréntesis en dos `isset()`, no había agregado la conexión en `mysqli_prepare()` y error tipográfico en `bind_param`.

Comment: Ya no da error ni nada, Lo agradezco muchisimo!
Pero cuando inicio sesion no pasa, aunque ponga la contraseña y usuario correcto no me manda a xAdmin.php

Comment: ¿A dónde te lleva? Probablemente el error está desde el inicio, con la variable `$id_cargo`, porque no se ve dónde la usas. Cambia `if(empty($usuario) || empty($contra) || empty($cargo))` por `if(empty($usuario) || empty($contra))`

Comment: He hecho la modificacion y me sigue mandando al xLogin pero con fallo, aunque inserte la contraseña y usuarios correctos

Comment: Edita la pregunta para agregar código del formulario y lo que se muestra si agregas `var_dump($_POST);` en el script donde lo procesas.

Comment: Este es el codigo de mi formulario de login https://imgur.com/a/WAk2ESA

Comment: Me arroja esto "array(0) { }"

Comment: No me ha salido, ya he hecho algunos cambios y nada... Agradezco mucho el tiempo que tomaste por haberme ayudado! :)